# Disable text wrapping

Tags: html, css

Here is table with email and checkbox cells. But how i can disable textwrapping?

Code is someting like:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" />
<td>
Dmitry soloviev (SolDmitr@mail.com)
</tr>
...........
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Hey are you interested in avoiding scroll bar than simplest way is to use `overflow:hidden` property in css for table. And if your intentions are different then please clarify the question.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

you should add some classes ...

```
<table class="tbl-emails">
```

and then

```
.tbl-emails td { white-space: nowrap; }
```

Answer (score 21):

(Add to your CSS Selector).

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

Answer (score 7):

The white-space attribute allows you to prevent text from wrapping until you place a break 
 into your text.

```
p { white-space: nowrap; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also check the property overflow-x: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp